Error when trying to send a message from Faceboook page to Facebook user using API
When I'm trying to use Graph API to send a message from FB page to an user. I get this error:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '100066276464105' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "AkMoCKVHuPHXAT7IQubn6rE"
  }
}

I have checked the other document and see this issue related with missing permission on my Facebook app, but I already has
"pages_show_list" permission:

"pages_read_engagement" and "pages_read_user_content":

"pages_manage_ads":

This is my Graph API call:

Have someone got the same issue as me?
UPDATED:
I have try again and this is the current issue that I have
Step 1: I using GET method to get my user id (UID)

Step 2: Then I get my facebook page Id (PID)

Step 3: Then I using my user to send the initial message to the facebook page, after that I use the POST call to send response message to the initial message.

Where do I go wrong?

Pages cannot start a conversation with a user. They can only reply once a user starts a conversation with the page, and only for a certain period of time.

@ceejayoz in my call, I set the message_type is RESPONSE, and I have sent a message from the user to the page with in 24 hours then I try the API call and I thought it should works, but the issue still show up.

The reason for this one is I need to get my PSID user.
To do this I need to go to
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/LATEST-API-VERSION/PAGE-ID/conversations?fields=participants&access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN"

Then response will be something like this, then the Id in the response will be the PSID and using this PSID to send the message

